# Create method in WebService (JAX-WS) to send data to mysql DB

Tags: java, mysql, web-services, jax-ws

***Hi everybody..***

I'm new to web services so tried to create simple web service (jax-ws) on glass fish server 4.1.1, this service sending data to mysql database like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irQOV.png)  but I'm getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JreKA.png) error why I don't know!?!?

MY CODES:

```
    package com.me.coder;

    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import javax.jws.WebService;
    import javax.jws.WebMethod;
    import javax.jws.WebParam;

    /**
     *
     * @author MacbookPro
     */
    @WebService(serviceName = "GetWriteToDB")
    public class GetWriteToDB {

        /**
         * Web service operation
         */

        @WebMethod(operationName = "sendToDb")
        public void sendToDb(@WebParam(name = "id") int id, @WebParam(name = "name") String name, @WebParam(name = "location") double location, @WebParam(name = "date") String date) {
           String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/onurDB";
            String user = "onur";
            String pass = "onurdb958";

            try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host,user,pass);
                Statement smt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);   
               ){
                String SQL = "INSERT INTO `GoogleLoc`(`ID`, `NAME`, `LOCATION`, `DATE`) VALUES ('" + id + "','" + name + "','"+ location + "','" + date + "')";
                smt.executeUpdate(SQL);

            }catch(SQLException ex){
                System.out.println("SQLException : " + ex);
            }  

        }
    }
```

For control,same codes tried using in java SE class worked perfectly.
 Like this:

```
package send;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

/**
 *
 * @author MacbookPro
 */
public class Send {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    private static String name,date;
    private static int location,id;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/onurDB";
        String user = "onur";
        String pass = "onurdb958";

        try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host,user,pass);
            Statement smt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);   
           ){

            insertData(smt);
        }catch(SQLException ex){
            System.out.println("SQLException : " + ex);
        }  
    }
       private static void insertData(Statement smt) throws SQLException, IOException {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Enter ID : ");
        String id = bf.readLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Name : ");
        String name = bf.readLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Location : ");
        String location = bf.readLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Date : ");
        String date = bf.readLine();
        String sql;
        sql = "INSERT INTO `GoogleLoc`(`ID`, `NAME`, `LOCATION`, `DATE`) VALUES ('" + id + "','" + name + "','"
                + location + "','" + date + "')";
        smt.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("Success! data inserted.");
    }
}
```

I can imagine my fault in @WebMethod

Somebody can help me please???

THANKS FOR ALL..

Comment: in your screenshot, we have  not the end of the stacktrace.

Comment: @davidhxxx It doesn't show much more than...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved !**

We need to change codes like this :

```
    package com.me.coder;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;

/**
 *
 * @author Coder ACJHP
 */
@WebService(serviceName = "GetWriteToDB")
public class GetWriteToDB {

    /**
     * Web service operation
     *
     * @param id
     * @param name
     * @param location
     * @param date
     * @return
     */
    @GET
    @WebMethod(operationName = "insertUser")
    public boolean insertUser(@WebParam(name = "id") int id, @WebParam(name = "name") String name,
            @WebParam(name = "location") double location, @WebParam(name = "date") String date) {
        boolean insertStatus = false;
        final String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/onurDB";
        final String user = "onur";
        final String pass = "onurdb958";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(GetWriteToDB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try (
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host, user, pass);
                Statement smt = conn.createStatement();) {
            String SQL = "INSERT INTO `GoogleLoc`(`ID`, `NAME`, `LOCATION`, `DATE`) VALUES ('" + id + "','" + name + "','" + location + "','" + date + "')";
            int x = smt.executeUpdate(SQL);
            if (x > 0) {
                insertStatus = true;
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        return insertStatus;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your `NullPointerException` is raised from the `WebserviceTesterServlet` class  which is a GlassFish WS tool class for helping you to call a webservice. It's a graphical client for your webservice.
Maybe, the problem comes from this class, maybe from your implementation.
With this stracktrace, it is hard to guess.

The problem is that `WebserviceTesterServlet` doesn't give a helpful exception.
So, we cannot understand the cause.
I propose you three solutions to solve your problem :

- Download the source jar containing `WebserviceTesterServlet` (take the version you use), put a breakpoint on the line 342 of this class and run your server in debug mode.
- Trying with SOAP UI for calling your operation.
- Create your own code for calling the webService and test your webservice operation. You can do it easily by generating the proxy classes. You can use for example use JAX-WS and do a wsimport.

Comment: I will try and tell you what happened.

Comment: @davidxxx My friend i tried it in own app and there is no error or any problem?!?! but nothing added to database.

Comment: I found the problem... this web service not allow to use method(void) only I can use constructor (return).Just changed the method to constructor with return any thing it's worked!...........So how I can use void?

Comment: @Coder ACJHP

Great :)

 but a void method is not a constructor :)
You changed the method return type :)
Can you try with SOAPUI ?
I wonder if the problem doesn't come from the glassfish UI.
If it's not the case, you should look the output message in the xsd

Comment: Finally, you have succeeded ? you are welcome Good luck :)